# Cluster pixels into region with same color in dithered images

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, pixel

I need to locate dense regions in similar images, where density depends on distance between pixels. The pixels that have distance less then some threshold are to be included in a group. The white boxes show the results that I want. Any ideas or existing algorithms would be welcome.

[image]

Comment: Why do you say *"similar"* images? Similar to what? If they are similar to each other, are they a video sequence - in which case you may be able to benefit from some kind of tracking. If they are similar to something else, can we see that please?

Comment: You could try dilating the green regions using morphology to join the pixels into solid clumps then do a Connected Components analysis to find the blobs. Or you could box filter and look for maxima of intensity.

Comment: @MarkSetchell dilate approach is *exactly* what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few experiments just on the command line with **ImageMagick** which is on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

First, I removed your white annotations and thresholded for black and white:

```
convert PaOdy.jpg -fill black -fuzz 20% -opaque white -threshold 20% clean.png
```

[image]

Then I tried blur 3x3 and threshold:

```
convert clean.png -blur 3x3 -threshold 20% z.png
```

[image]

Then I tried blur 5x5 and threshold:

```
convert clean.png -blur 5x5 -threshold 20% z.png
```

[image]

Then I tried blur, threshold and dilation to fill the shapes out:

```
convert clean.png -blur 5x5 -threshold 20% -morphology dilate disk:5 z.png
```

[image]

Obviously you can vary the sizes and thresholds to suit your needs. Then I tried *"Connected Components Analysis"* (also referred to as "labelling" and "Blob Analysis") to find blobs of pixels as follows:

```
convert clean.png -blur 5x5 -threshold 20%  \
     -morphology dilate disk:5              \
     -define connected-components:verbose=1 \
     -connected-components 8 -auto-level    \
     result.png
```

**Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 627x459+0+0 309.0,225.9 269780 srgb(0,0,0)
  18: 145x72+326+387 392.5,421.0 7378 srgb(255,255,255)      <--- This blob
  5: 87x58+304+60 349.5,90.2 2194 srgb(255,255,255)
  11: 128x35+239+186 300.2,202.2 2011 srgb(255,255,255)
  1: 52x41+447+36 471.1,54.7 1107 srgb(255,255,255)
  8: 43x21+441+170 462.9,180.3 678 srgb(255,255,255)
  2: 28x32+502+37 514.2,50.5 611 srgb(255,255,255)
  17: 26x31+134+298 145.9,313.4 608 srgb(255,255,255)
  22: 52x24+373+435 396.6,451.7 513 srgb(0,0,0)
  14: 27x24+187+231 199.6,242.1 433 srgb(255,255,255)
  10: 30x18+385+181 399.0,189.0 431 srgb(255,255,255)
  6: 22x26+565+83 575.2,95.5 400 srgb(255,255,255)
  21: 31x17+409+418 421.9,425.0 298 srgb(0,0,0)
  4: 18x19+536+50 544.4,58.8 243 srgb(255,255,255)
  15: 19x17+60+261 69.1,269.3 221 srgb(255,255,255)
  3: 17x13+602+49 609.6,54.8 162 srgb(255,255,255)
  9: 15x14+422+179 429.0,185.8 147 srgb(255,255,255)
  23: 16x10+99+449 106.8,454.2 128 srgb(255,255,255)
  13: 14x13+224+216 230.4,221.9 127 srgb(255,255,255)
  7: 13x12+212+101 218.0,106.5 116 srgb(255,255,255)
  16: 12x11+126+274 131.5,279.0 92 srgb(255,255,255)
  12: 11x12+19+201 24.0,206.5 92 srgb(255,255,255)
  20: 5x7+377+415 379.5,417.4 20 srgb(0,0,0)
  19: 2x2+397+407 397.7,407.3 3 srgb(0,0,0)
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see in the image each *"blob"* gets its own colour (shade of grey) which means all the pixels in a blob are labelled with the same number.

If we now analyse the textual output, looking for example, at the line like this:

```
18: 145x72+326+387 392.5,421.0 7378 srgb(255,255,255)
```

you can see it is 145 pixels wide and 72 pixels tall and starts at coordinates 326,387 from the top-left. Then we see its area and colour etc. Let's box that in in red:

```
convert clean.png -stroke red -fill none -draw "rectangle 326,387 471,458 " z.png
```

[image]

---

I am just sharing ideas simply on the command line here without any need to compile etc. You can implement the above in C++ with OpenCV, or in Python with OpenCV, or in C++ with CImg, or in Python with PIL (Pillow).

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying that I have never solved this particular problem. But here is an idea I could see working.

I'd make a list of the coordinates of each pixel that has the color you want. I'd then also put them into a [quad-tree structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). I'd then go through the list and compare each pixel against any pixel that's within a quad that's less than or equal to the distance in question. This should significantly reduce the number of comparisons you need to make.